# In iOS,How to sync CBL with server through terminal without using CouchDB dmg?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I trying to run sync gateway code into the terminal but i don't understand how it works, even through needless response. see the code below,

```
{
"log": ["HTTP+"],
"databases": {
    "grocery-sync": {
        "server": "http://localhost:8091",
        "bucket": "grocery-sync",
        "users": {
        "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] }}}}
```

}

But,i getting below response but i couldn't understand what exactly need to do for auto replication.

[image]

Comment: In Couchbase Lite [setup a replication](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) that uses 'http://<server-ip>:4984/sync-gateway' as its URL.  The config file you show and the output don't match up though.  One is setup to use Couchbase Server, one is set up to use the flat file dev environment 'walrus' (neither will use CouchDB, Sync Gateway is not something that is used with CouchDB)

Comment: Sync Gateway is a separate server.  You normally communicate with it using Couchbase Lite as an embedded client, or through its REST APIs.

The response you're showing above is the normal console logging that Sync Gateway does.

Sync Gateway communicates with Couchbase Server based on the parameters given in the config file.